# build qt application with qbs

Tags: android, qt, qbs

I would like to know the steps to compile, build and create a Qt application for android using qbs on linux. I have all the necessary tools, and currently I can create an apk using qmake.

Comment: See http://doc.qt.io/qbs/

Comment: Building for Android might not be currently supported by qbs. Maybe in next version of Qt Creator. If you need to build for Desktop I can give you an example link if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Qbs does not currently support building Qt/Android applications. Preliminary support for Android was introduced in Qbs v1.4, but Qt support is not yet available.