# Qt QBS and android

Tags: android, qt, qbs

I'm trying to find a simple tutorial: how to make a simple application for android using gbps. The following links were found:

1. [Stack oferflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898075/build-qt-application-with-qbs). The answer to this question has not been
   received, although the version of the cbs has already been updated
   to 1.11 and the support of android is included.
2. [AndroidApk Item in QBS Documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qbs/qml-qbsconvenienceitems-androidapk.html). In this case I get warning: `'../Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' does not exist.`

I unfortunately could not find any new information. I ask for help.

**Update:**
For Qmake I just create standard widget project like this one:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = androidtest
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY =
```

And this is works and builds fine. QtCreator automatically create all necessary files and than run  app on my phone

In Qbs I try to make same application. For this reason I have QBS-file:

```
import qbs

Project {
    CppApplication {
        name: "helloworld"

        Depends {
            name: "Qt"
            submodules: [
                "core",
                "widgets"
            ]
        }

        Depends { name: "Android.ndk" }
        Android.ndk.appStl: "gnustl_shared"

        Group {
            name: "src"
            files: [
                "main*.*"

            ]
        }
    }

    AndroidApk {
        name: "helloworld_android"
        Depends {name: "helloworld" }
        packageName: "com.example.android.helloworld"
    }
}
```

At the end I have Done with HelloWorld product (libhelloworld.so). But first error of "helloworld_android" is a fail at android manifest. This file is undefined. What I should do next?

Comment: You should paste your project file here (or link to the project if it is available on the internet), so we know what you tried to do exactly.

Comment: Christian, at the moment I do a lot of things wrong. I'm just starting to work with QBS and android. I would like to get any example ("Hello world") in order to use it later for work. I know that you belong to the group of developers of this project (QBS) and would like to get a simple example that I could build for the android with QBS. I pray to share it.

Comment: There really isn't much to a Hello World project on the qbs side: You use the normal Android project structure (Java sources, assets, resources, manifest file etc) and point your qbs project to it. For instance, this is a qbs project file for one of the sample projects in the Android SDK: https://github.com/qbs/qbs/blob/master/tests/auto/blackbox/testdata-android/no-native/no-native.qbs. Then build it with a profile that you set up with the setup-android tool (https://doc.qt.io/qbs/cli-setup-android.html).

Comment: Please see on Update to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I made it. It's not a good solution but this is work. Resulting APK you can find in "\install-root\$productName$\build\outputs\apk\$productName$-debug.apk

```
import qbs
import qbs.TextFile
import qbs.Process
import qbs.File

Project {
    //Main Application
    CppApplication {
        name: "helloworld";

        Depends {
            name: "Qt"
            submodules: [
                "core",
                "widgets"
            ]
        }

        Depends { name: "Android.ndk" }
        Android.ndk.appStl: "gnustl_shared"

        Group {
            name: "src"
            files: [
                "main*.*"
            ]
        }
        Group {
            qbs.install: true
            fileTagsFilter: "dynamiclibrary"
            qbs.installPrefix : product.name+"/libs/"+Android.ndk.abi+"/"
        }
    }

    //Preparation
    Product {
        name: "Prepared2Deploy"
        type: "prepared2deploy"
        Depends { name: "helloworld" }
        Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
        Depends { name: "Android.ndk" }
        Depends { name: "Android.sdk" }
        Rule {
            inputsFromDependencies: "installable"
            Artifact {
                filePath: input.fileName+".json"
                fileTags: "prepared2deploy"
            }
            prepare: {
                var cmd = new JavaScriptCommand();
                cmd.description = "prepare for androidDeployQt";
                cmd.highlight = "install";
                cmd.sourceCode = function() {
                    var outputFile = new TextFile(output.filePath, TextFile.WriteOnly);
                    outputFile.writeLine("{");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"qt\": \"" + product.Qt.core.binPath.replace(/\/bin$/,"") + "\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"sdk\": \"" + product.Android.sdk.sdkDir + "\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"sdkBuildToolsRevision\": \"" + product.Android.sdk.buildToolsVersion + "\",");
                    var ndkDir = product.Android.ndk.ndkDir.replace(/\\/g,"/"); //why sdk ndk get wrong slashes?
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"ndk\": \""+ndkDir+"\",");
                    var toolchain =  product.cpp.toolchainPrefix.replace(/-$/,"");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"toolchain-prefix\": \"" + toolchain + "\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"tool-prefix\": \"" + toolchain + "\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"toolchain-version\": \"4.9\",");   //how I can get it ???
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"ndk-host\": \"windows-x86_64\","); //how I can get it ???
                    var abi = product.Android.ndk.abi
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"target-architecture\": \""+abi+"\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"stdcpp-path\": \""+ndkDir+"/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/" + //how I can get it ???
                                         abi+"/lib"+product.Android.ndk.appStl+".so\",");
                    outputFile.writeLine("     \"application-binary\": \""+ input.filePath+"\"");
                    outputFile.writeLine("}");
                    outputFile.close();
                }
                return cmd;
            }
        }
    }
    //Deployer
    Product {
        name: "AndroidDeployQt"
        Depends { name: "helloworld" }
        id: androidDeployQt
        type: "androidDeployQt"
        Depends {name: "Qt.core" }

        Rule {
            inputsFromDependencies: "prepared2deploy"
            alwaysRun: true
            Artifact {
                filePath: "log.txt"
                fileTags: "androidDeployQt"
            }
            prepare: {
                var cmd = new JavaScriptCommand();
                cmd.description = "androidDeployQt";
                cmd.highlight = "install";
                cmd.sourceCode = function() {
                    var logFile = new TextFile(output.filePath, TextFile.WriteOnly);
                    logFile.writeLine(input.fileName);
                    var productName = input.fileName.replace(/.so.json$/,"").replace(/^(lib)/,"");
                    var androidDeployProcess = new Process();
                    var exitCode = androidDeployProcess.exec(product.Qt.core.binPath+"/androiddeployqt.exe",
                                                             [
                                                                 "--input", input.filePath,
                                                                 "--output", project.buildDirectory+"/install-root/"+productName,
                                                                 "--android-platform", "android-25", //???
                                                                 "--gradle"
                                                             ])
                    if (exitCode) {
                        console.error("Error at androidDeployProcess. Error code: "+exitCode);
                        console.error(androidDeployProcess.readStdErr());
                        console.error("FULL_LOG: ");
                        console.error(androidDeployProcess.readStdOut());
                    }
                    logFile.close();
                }
                return cmd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

qmake has some built-in magic when building for Android, like using resources provided by Qt (including a manifest template) and running the android-deployqt tool. None of this is currently done by qbs.

Comment: This is very bad answer. Ok, I think I need made self some module for preparing android apk with Qbs with androiddeployqt.exe. In this case for what need AndroidApk Item in Qbs

Answer (score 0):

QBS 1.13, released on February this year (2019) makes deploying an Android application as simple as with qmake. In practice, you don't need to do anything special. For example, I took the [contactlist application from the Qt examples](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/contactlist?h=5.14) and added this QBS file:

```
import qbs 1.0

Project {
    QtGuiApplication {
        name: "contactlist"
        install: true

        files: [
            "contactmodel.h",
            "contactmodel.cpp",
            "main.cpp",
        ]

        Group {
            files: [
                "*.qml",
                "designer/Backend/*.qml",
                "designer/Backend/qmldir",
            ]
            fileTags: ["qt.core.resource_data"]
        }

        Depends { name: "Qt.quick" }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's nothing specific to Android here. The only trick I'm using is to assign the tag `qt.core.resource_data` to the QML files in order to have them compiled as resource files — but it's not even required.

With `qbs run` the application will be run in your connected Android device.